# Capybara Radio button not choosable

Tags: ruby, capybara

for the below element html code i ve tried multiple ways, Radio button is not choosable at all. Can someone help

```
<fieldset class="usa-fieldset-inputs usa-sans">
<input type="radio" name="certificate_type" id="idvalue" value="xx">
<label for="add_certificate">xxxx<a href="../prepare#xx-anc" target="_blank">(Review requirements)</a>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="certificate_type" id="ddddd" value="xxx">
<label for="add_certificate">xxxxx <a href="../prepare#xxx-anc" target="_blank">(Review requirements)</a>
</label>
```

tried all below

```
choose("certificate_type")
choose("idvalue")
page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="idvalue"]').click
and other xpaths also. Xpath seems to be good.
```

Comment: does `choose('xx')` work for you?

Comment: Nop tried that too.Actually even xpath does not work. I checked page html,  its able to find elements  within this page.

Comment: You need to provide the error messages generated by each of your failed tries, the first one won't work because you have multiple elements with "certificate_type" as a name, but if your inputs are actually visible on the page (which you claim) the `choose('idvalue')` should work